# Appending to list - None result

Tags: python, append

**Data:**

```
lis_t = [['q', 'w', 'e'],['r', 't', 'y']]
```

**Expected Outcome:**

```
lis_t = [['q', 'w', 'e', 'u'],['r', 't', 'y']]
```

**problem description:** I am trying to append to the list above however not able to append the same as it somehow results in none. Please help me understand what am I doing wrong.

**Code written:**

```
lis_t = [['q', 'w', 'e'],['r', 't', 'y']]
lis_t[0] = lis_t[0].append('u')
print(lis_t[0])
print(lis_t)
```

**output:**

```
None
[None, ['r', 't', 'y']]
```

Comment: istead of `lis_t[0] = lis_t[0].append('u')` write `lis_t[0].append('u')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lis_t[0].append('u')` this returns `None` value and then you assigning this to `lis_t[0]` that's why you are getting `None` value

```
lis_t = [['q', 'w', 'e'],['r', 't', 'y']]
lis_t[0].append('u')
print(lis_t)
```

Answer (score 4):

do this

```
lis_t = [['q', 'w', 'e'],['r', 't', 'y']]
lis_t[0].append('u')
print(lis_t)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add some explanatory text as to why this works and why the original method did not.

Answer (score 0):

Python function always return value when invoked. If no return value provided it will return `None`.

python `list.append()` is function which have no return value so it will be returning `None` when invoked.

what you are doing is assigning the `list.append()` method invocation to `lis_t[0]`

so the correct way in your case is.

```
lis_t[0].append('u')
```

Answer (score 0):

apart from

```
list_t[0].append('u')
```

you can do (if you like to use the '+')

```
list_t[0] += ['u']
```

or

```
list_t[0] = list_t[0] + ['u']
```

The result is always this

```
print(list_t[0])

>>> ['q', 'w', 'e', 'u']
```